# Roundcube 1.5.0 upgrade: Internal Server Error

Tags: centos7, roundcube, webmail

My server updated automatically to this new release of Roundcube 1.5, since then, Roundcube don't show any Inbox mail with the message "Internal Server Error".

I tried and searched for possible solutions, but found nothing to solve.

Is a Centos 7 with PHP 7.4 and Mysql server.

Can you suggest an action plan?

Comment: Check your logs and journal for relevant error messages.

Comment: Wich logs you suggest? I looked  dovecot and maillog in /var/log and found nothing to help

Comment: The error logs of your webserver of course. That's where the error comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case using `Control-WebPanel [CWP]`, just run these tow commands in ssh:

```
/scripts/update_cwp
/scripts/mail_roundcube_update
```

---

In case you install `Roundcube` manually, this problem will happen if you upgrade to `Roundcube 1.5 version` and `PHP intl extension` not installed and activated, so:

1. Check the `PHP version` which your `Roundcube` run on it, to know it edit `index.php` which located in `Roundcube` path, and add this line on header of file:

> echo phpinfo();

Then save file, and open url of `Roundcube` in browser, you will see all information about version of PHP which used by `Roundcube` Including `php.ini` path, (do not forget delete line after that).

2- Enable `PHP intl Extension`, the exact steps for that depends on your PHP version, many questions on `Stackoverflow` explain how to do that, like: [how can I enable PHP Extension intl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl)

Comment: Great! Your answer solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I also performed the upgrade using the complete version from the [official source](https://roundcube.net/download/) and I found the following error in my journal:

```
Oct 20 21:39:21 [hostname] roundcube[1258]: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Spoofchecker' not found in /var/www/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_spoofchecker.php:50
                                        Stack trace:
                                        #0 /var/www/webmail/program/actions/mail/index.php(1400): rcube_spoofchecker::check('gmail.com')
                                        #1 /var/www/webmail/program/actions/mail/index.php(523): rcmail_action_mail_index::address_string('[removed]...', 3, false, NULL, 'utf-8')
                                        #2 /var/www/webmail/program/actions/mail/list.php(123): rcmail_action_mail_index::js_message_list(Array, false, Array)
                                        #3 /var/www/webmail/program/include/rcmail.php(275): rcmail_action_mail_list->run(Array)
                                        #4 /var/www/webmail/index.php(283): rcmail->action_handler()
                                        #5 {main}
                                          thrown in /var/www/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_spoofchecker.php on line 50
```

The relevant part is:

```
Class 'Spoofchecker' not found
```

This closed issue report [Uncaught Error: Class 'Spoofchecker' not found #8127](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/issues/8127#issuecomment-877759873-permalink) suggested that the package **`php-intl`** is now a **new requirement**. This [forum post](https://www.roundcubeforum.net/index.php/topic,29680.0.html#subject_75407) gives more details:

> According to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63790 the Spoofchecker is only available when PHP intl extension is built with ICU >= 4.2. So, I suspect your build does not have it, but it is required.

So it depends on your system, if `php-intl` needs to be installed. On newer systems, it is not necessary.

Installing `php-intl` depending on your system:
Fedora/CentOS/RedHat/etc.:

```
dnf install php-intl
```

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt install php-intl
```

Don't forget to restart your webserver.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I was aware about this extension and even after install the problem was not solved.

Comment: Okay, as you didn't show any logs, it was pure guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have control over your php installation, you can comment out this code in program/actions/mail/index.php to skip this:

```
        // Homograph attack detection (#6891)
        //if (!self::$SUSPICIOUS_EMAIL) {
        //    self::$SUSPICIOUS_EMAIL = rcube_spoofchecker::check($mailto);
        //}
```